# Polymer array won't update UI when changed

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

A lot of Polymer 1.0 problems today,

My HTML look like this:

```
<section class="layout vertical" id="onlineList">
        <paper-item class="subdue layout horizontal center">Online Now</paper-item>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{cats}}" as="cat">
            <paper-item>{{cat}}</paper-item>
        </template>
</section>
```

As you can see I'm trying to loop out each `cat` in the array `cats`. My problem is that the `cats`-array changes about 4 times. The first time it has one `cat`, second time two..and so on, until there is no more changes. But it seems that the only change that is propogated to the UI is the first `cat`.

The cats array is changed in a callback called `presenceChanged` which PubNub calls when the "online"-list changes, see below:

```
template.presenceChanged = function(e) {
    var l = template.$.sub.presence.length;
    var d = template.$.sub.presence[l - 1];

    // who are online
    if(d.action === 'join') {
        if(d.uuid.length > 35) { // console
            d.uuid = 'the-mighty-big-cat';
        }
        onlineUuids.push(d.uuid);
    } else {
        var idx = onlineUuids.indexOf(d.uuid);
        if(idx > -1) {
            onlineUuids.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    }

    // display at the left column
    template.cats = onlineUuids;

    //.. some code
};
```

So, just to clarify. The presentChanged-callback is called, lets say 4 times. And each time the list will contain one more cat (so it's called once for every user which is in the "room"). In the "last" call it will look like: `["cat_1","cat_2","cat_3","cat_4"]` but only `["cat_1"]` will be shown UI-wise, why? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the the array mutation methods provided by the Polymer elements (see [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat) on `dom-repeat`):

> Mutations to the items array itself (push, pop, splice, shift, unshift) must be performed using methods provided on Polymer elements, such that the changes are observable to any elements bound to the same array in the tree. For example

In your example you need to use `this.push('cats', d.uuid);` instead of the `push` method on the actual array. (same thing applies to the `splice`, etc)

Comment: Ahh I suspected it might be something like this, but couldn't find anything about it. Thanks a lot. Will try this later today!

Comment: Do you happen to know if this is a change from what it was in Polymer 0.5?

Comment: Yes it is one of the changes. 
0.5 was relying on dirty checking which is slow. 
1.0 relies more in imperative notifications and setters to propogate changes.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Will be interesting to see all the performance improvements.

Comment: Hello again, just wanted some clarification. Finally got the time to try your solution out but. In my example you can see that my "cats" array is "template.cats" where template is: template = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('template[is=dom-bind]'). How will I go on about to make this work as in your example?

Comment: the same way.  In your `presenceChanged` function `this` will point to the `dom-bind` element that implements the array mutation functions that are part of [Polymer.Base](http://polymer.github.io/polymer/) class.

Comment: Thank you! The reason it didn't work was because template.cats wasn't initialized as an array (because of the previous way it was done). In other words, "this" works as you said.